# How do I set up a circuit in order to help me measure the resistance of a 1-meter length copper wire with changes in temperature?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, physics

I am a high school student and I am taking Physics at school. I have been given the task of measuring the resistance of a copper wire with changes in temperature, however, I have no prior knowledge of electricity and how circuits work. At school, I only have access to a few multimeters, a power supply, some crocodile clips, copper wire, and an IR camera. My teacher has suggested that I change the temperature of the copper wire by using the power supply, and to measure the temperature of the wire using the IR camera, however, I have no idea how to change the temperature, or by how much to change it, or what real effect it will have on the wire if I change the numbers on the power supply. I carried out a preliminary experiment, however, as I turned on the power supply which was on +100 VDC (which I don't even know what that means), I saw a decrease in the number on the multimeter when measuring resistance, and I have no idea what happened there. I'm not sure if there is anything else that I could do, or how I could do it. If there is a better way to carry out the experiment that I have been asked to carry out in a high-school environment, I am just not aware of it. I would truly appreciate it if anybody could help me understand and identify what I could do for my experiment, and how I could carry it out.

Comment: It is completely unreasonable to allow a student to work with 100 VDC without any supervision, and thats assuming that the student knows what they are doing. At companies where people have engineering degrees (4+ years) there are mandatory buddy systems for high voltage work. This is dangerous stuff to be learning on the fly.

Comment: It sounds to me that you have been pushed out into the deep end without any training with an idea to see if have the ability to swim or will, instead, just drown. Perhaps that's how your high school physics works. But it shouldn't be. You should be provided with some thinking tools, and a minimum of safety guidelines and someone to observe who will keep you from making fatal mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Even after ignoring safety concerns, I don't think that heating the resistor by applying larger voltages is the best method. I would prefer a 4-wire (kelvin) measurement at some constant current to produce a couple hundred millivolts at most (I wouldn't want to push more than 100mA or so). For changing temperature I'd want a dedicated oven with temperature control.

There are simpler methods but I would suggest learning a bit more background and seeing if you can do a more suitable experiment.

Comment: That definitely makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much for the feedback. I will ask my teacher if there is anything that I can do with that information in a high school environment.

Answer (score 0):

A question: does your power supply have variable current limiting? With luck, it will have two adjustment knobs - one labelled voltage and the other labelled current. You can check this by setting the current limit at a minimum, the voltage at some medium value, and shorting the output. Then, as you adjust the current limit control, the display of the supply should show the output current varying.

Assuming this is true, you can make a circuit like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp4qDT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now you can vary the current, while recording the voltage. Since all the current goes through the wire, you can calculate the resistance of the wire using Ohm's Law.

If you do this while you look at the wire with the IR camera, you should see that the wire gets hotter the more current you pass through it. This is due to the fact that the wire will dissipate power equal to the square of the current times the resistance of the wire.

Another way to do this, if the supply does not have a current limit, is to do something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEHC24.png)</sup>

This will require two meters, one to measure current and the other to measure voltage. You can use a single resistor and vary the voltage of the supply. If you do this, make sure that you use a high-power resistor to limit the current. It will need to dissipate about the square of the supply voltage divided by the resistor value, and for high voltages this will produce a LOT of heat.

If you overheat the resistor, you may Let The Magic Smoke Out. Did you know that electronics is magic, and every component has a core with a pocket of magic smoke which actually makes it work? And if you blow out the casing, the Magic Smoke escapes at the same time the part stops working. Well, you have to admit that this explanation is at least self-consistent.

Sorry if I've confused you, but it's a classic electronics joke.

In either case, be aware that your results will be fairly crude. The problem is that it's hard to ensure that the entire wire stays at the same temperature. And your IR camera may not be terribly accurate when imaging a target as small as the cross-section of a wire. As another answer remarked, to do it right you should put the wire in an oven with a good temperature control and attention paid to making sure any heat loss occurs uniformly over the entire wire - and this is not easy.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you so much for all of that information. I will check back on the apparatus that we have at my school to see if I can carry out something similar to what you have illustrated above.